# yup schema for values between 0-1 only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik, yup

How can I modify the schema such that a user is only allowed to add values between 0-0.9?

```
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      ratio: Yup.number()
        .max(15, 'Must be 15 characters or less')
        .required('Required'),
    }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
Yup.object().shape({
   ratio : Yup.number().min(0).max(0.9)
});
```